# in sails set controller as default route instead of view

Tags: sails.js

in config/routes.js what happens when controller is needed instead of view

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'index'
  }

};
```

basically I want to load some data on the index page but I cant because there is no controller, in addition I want to have other pages like about, contact etc... but I prefer to put them to a PublicController instead of routes.js

Comment: just to answer part of my question I managed to replace view with controller: 'public', action: 'index' which allows me to use the PublicController. im still wondering if there is there a way for it to work without action!

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question, may be you are looking for something this,

```
module.exports.routes = {
    '/': {
        controller: 'User',
        action: 'actionName'
    }
};
```

At first I didn't notice your comment. If you want to put all of those sections under different routes(like `/about` for about section) then there is no way to do it very simply.

But yes I have done it using `React.js` front end framework, where you can define routes in a single view file using `React Routes`. Defining in `routes.js` is not necessary. Rendering that single file from only one controller would enable you to use all those routes defined in that view file. Can't tell you any other way.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As your comments show you can specific the controller, action in your routes.

In your controllers you can specify the view to be rendered.

```
PublicController.js
module.exports = {
    randomAction : function(req,res,next){

       res.view('./randomActionViewFile');

    }
}
```

Note this is unnecessary if the view file is already in the folder structure `api/views/public/randaomActionFile.ext`. Instead you can just use `res.ok`